# Snowflake Temporary Table Sequencing

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do a performance comparison between CTEs (WITH) and Temporary Tables. I've converted the query to utilized Temp tables but am seeing a scenario where the execution fails when run as a whole because one of the early temporary table executions gets cancelled.
SAMPLE:

```
// Produces large result set
CREATE temporary table tt1 as
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.c1
  FROM t1
  //ADDITIONAL LOGIC
  ;

CREATE temporary table tt2 as
SELECT t2.c1
    t2.c2
FROM t2;

CREATE temporary table tt3 as
SELECT t1.c1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN tt1
 on t1.c1 = tt1.c1;
```

The execution seems to get cancelled as tt3 begins to run, there is a dependency from tt3 back to tt1.
I have tried CTAS as well as defining the table with a standard `CREATE TABLE` then doing an `INSERT INTO` but it results in the same where the execution gets cancelled.

Is there a way to sequence these better via standard sql syntax without having to go the route of a stored procedure or task?

Edit[2]
Here is a simpler scenario using the COVID dataset that behaves the same.  Termination in both cases seems to be around 35 seconds.  So for replication purposes if you can generate a query that runs for 2 minutes, then create a simple subsequent temporary table that selects from the first you should be able to replicate.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE PLATFORM_EVALUATIONS.PUBLIC.TT1 AS
select a.COUNTRY_REGION
    , a.PROVINCE_STATE
    , a.COUNTY
    , current_date() c_date
    , count(*) counts
from PUBLIC.JHU_COVID_19_TIMESERIES a
inner join public.jhu_dashboard_covid_19_global b
 on a.country_region = b.country_region
where 1=1
and a.COUNTRY_REGION = 'United States'
group by a.COUNTRY_REGION
    , a.PROVINCE_STATE
    , a.COUNTY;
    
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE PLATFORM_EVALUATIONS.PUBLIC.TT2 AS
SELECT COUNTRY_REGION
    , COUNTS
FROM PLATFORM_EVALUATIONS.PUBLIC.TT1;
```

Edit[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDKIm.png):
[Work History Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDKIm.png)
You can see in the screen shot that _valid_barcodes (tt1) is cut short in duration (normally 2m 14s independently) and other steps begin prior to its completions/termination.

```
// this is tt1 in my example it produces 3,657,599 rows in 2m 14s but is cancelled short when run as a whole.
CREATE temporary table business_vault_dev.dnr._valid_barcodes as
  SELECT DISTINCT
    e.Barcode
  FROM BUSINESS_VAULT_DEV.DNR.DIM_EVENT_VW e
  INNER JOIN BUSINESS_VAULT_DEV.DNR.DIM_PACKAGE_VW p
    on e.BARCODE = COALESCE(p.Barcode, p.Barcode)
  INNER JOIN BUSINESS_VAULT_DEV.DNR.DIM_ORDER_VW o
    on p.order_key = o.order_key
  INNER JOIN BUSINESS_VAULT_DEV.SCORECARD.DIM_CUSTOMER_VW cl
    on o.CUSTOMER_ID=cl.CUSTOMER_ID
  WHERE e.Event_Type='Delivered'
    and o.service_code not in ('XD', 'PU')
    and lower(cl.NAME) IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
  GROUP BY e.Barcode
  HAVING date(min(e.EST_Event_DateTime)) between '2020-09-05' and '2020-10-02';

// this is tt2 
CREATE temporary table business_vault_dev.dnr._driver_merge as 
    select 
//redacted
    from data_lake.driver.driver_table1
    union
    select 
//redacted
    from data_lake.driver.driver_table2
    union
    select 
//redacted
    from data_lake.driver.driver_table3
    UNION
    select 
//redacted
    from data_lake.driver.driver_table4;

// this is unreferenced in my example but completes successfully and references the previous temp table    
CREATE temporary table business_vault_dev.dnr._driver as 
    select 
// redacted
    from business_vault_dev.dnr._driver_merge dm
    group by dm.contractor_number;

// this is tt3 in my example
CREATE temporary table business_vault_dev.dnr._slef_dedup as 
    SELECT
          e.Barcode
    // redacting columns here
    FROM BUSINESS_VAULT_DEV.DNR.DIM_EVENT_VW e
    INNER JOIN business_vault_dev.dnr._valid_barcodes vb
     ON e.Barcode = vb.Barcode
    LEFT JOIN data_lake.driver.driver_table1 cn
     ON //redacted
    LEFT JOIN data_lake.driver.driver_table2 pcp
     ON //redacted
;
```

Comment: Your final query looks like it would fail because `tt1` doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct, but what I see in the Job History is that t1 gets cancelled (thus not completing the creation of the table) as tt3 starts.  In smaller temporary tables this appears not to be an issue because the execution and load finishes before the next execution occurs

Comment: @DanielZagales Why does it get cancelled though? Is it by design?

Comment: That I do not know, I do not get much information on the cancelation.
`SQL execution canceled`
Which makes me believe I need to sequence the execution in some way to avoid it. I believe I can do it with tasks or stored procedures but am looking to stick with just sql.

Comment: Hi - if you run the statements individually, in the same order, and wait for each one to finish before starting the next one, do all 3 statements run OK?

Comment: Yes, if run individually in the same order everything performs as expected.

Comment: In the history, when tt1 fails, can you see tt2 running and then tt3? They should not be overlapping. Can you post a picture of these 3 jobs in the History (with all the columns shown) and can you also post the complete SQL for tt1? Thanks

Comment: can't reproduce - what environment are you using to run this code?

Comment: Updated the original ticket, this is running on a medium warehouse in the snowflake cloud environment.

Comment: I don't know about the issue you are running into, but you'll find no advantage to using temp tables over CTE.  Assuming that all of these statements are executed on the same warehouse during the same session, the queries after the temp table will need to read from storage, where a CTE will be able to leverage warehouse cache for subsequent queries.  All you're doing is increasing storage costs and likely compute time.  And yes...temp tables on Snowflake can be included in storage costs if they exist when the storage is computed.

Comment: Can you share your query profile. It may be getting cancelled and rerun because you do not have enough resource in the warehouse. Do you see step0001/step0002 in query profile?

Comment: I do see step1/step2 in the query profile with 1 having a status of finished, and 2 failed.

Comment: I've updated with a simpler example using the public covid dataset

Comment: I had no problem running this https://i.imgur.com/JtAGIgQ.png

Comment: Same as Felipe: the Covid SQL ran with no issues

Comment: So @FelipeHoffa I noticed your screenshot is in the "Old" UI, I'm getting failures in the Snowsight UI.  I executed in the "Old" UI and I'm not experiencing the issue and it successfully executes.

Comment: I tried in both, both worked for me. https://i.imgur.com/cmU7yRd.png

Comment: What is the size of your warehouse

Comment: I have attempted with both a XS and M, however I do not know that the size is the issue as currently I have a 100% success rate on an XS on the old UI.  And a lot of inconsistencies on the new UI using both XS and M with either `SQL compilation error: Object 'PLATFORM_EVALUATIONS.PUBLIC.TT1' does not exist or not authorized.`, `Query produced no results`, or very rarely a successful return.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, I am able to reproduce the issue on my tests using your simple scenario with COVID database. It seems there is an issue with the new UI. It starts to run the second CREATE TABLE command without finishing the first one. Please submit a ticket to Snowflake support.

It would be useful to generate and share a HAR file when submitting this ticket, and include SQL to reproduce.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-a-HAR-file-for-Web-Interface-Troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you Gokhan for confirming the behavior.
I've submitted a ticket with support.